# LESS files in Visual Studio not syntax highlighted

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

I have just installed Web Essentials 2012 for VS2012, but when I open a .less file, nothing is highlighted and the preview window doesn't display.  Are there any settings or something I am missing to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Web Essentials does not include Less tools anymore, you need to install the [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 update](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/fall-2012-update) to work with Less. A bit more details can be found [on Web Essential's developer's blog.](http://madskristensen.net/post/Web-Tools-20122-and-Web-Essentials.aspx)