# Less not work with WebEssentials in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

When i create a less file with .less extension, WebEssentials not show less syntax(intellisence, colored syntax) And not appear preview page, ever not known less files!

also all of less options in WebEssentials settings is enabled.

what is problem?

**SOLUTION:**
My Problem Not Solved by Installing Asp.Net Web Tools 2012.2.

I Solved Problem By Installing Web Developer Tools 2012.2 from => http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=282228

Comment: VTC - possible duplicate of [LESS files in Visual Studio not syntax highlighted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323250/less-files-in-visual-studio-not-syntax-highlighted) - see the answer there. Less support has been removed from WE2012.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing [Web Developer Tools 2012.2](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=282228)

Answer (score 11):

You need to install "ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2" to get the LESS editing experience to light up in VS.

Comment: Yes I installed "ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2" and new version of WebEssentials, But syntax highlighter and preview window doesn't work. please see this image: http://i.imgur.com/fhD0nmh.jpg

Answer (score 3):

I could not get VStudio 2012 to recognize the .less files either.
Finally, I went to *Tools...Extensions and Updates..*.
I then disabled the Web Essentials plugin (see image) by clicking the Disable button.
[image]

After that, Visual Studio will ask if you want to restart. Click the "Yes" button.
Next go back to *Tools...Extensions and Updates...*

Now, go ahead and go down to the Web Essentials item and select it.  You can now click the *Enable* button and restart again.

This time when it restarted my .less file now displayed the split screen, but I still couldn't see the .css file it generates at the left (see image).
I clicked the "Show All Files" up in solution explorer, but they still didn't show.
Finally, I double-clicked the .less file and it generated the split screen on the left and the list of gen'd files showed up.

[image: Files Generated by .less]

Comment: What is your VS Web Essentials version?

Comment: Web Essentials 2012 v3.2.  I just downloaded it yesterday (11/15/2013) from the web site.

Comment: Please use this,for VS 2012: https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids
and for VS 2013: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2911573

Comment: can i give custom path to save on to css generated by less?

Comment: Also, if this doesn't work. Make sure your .LESS file doesn't have any errors before you run it. It will not generate the file while you have errors in the file.